# Using GPU with fastai and pytorch

Tags: pytorch, fast-ai

I am using fastai and pytorch for image classification. I tried to train it on google colab. But it takes much time to train it on colab and I think the problem is GPU is not set properly. This is how I did it.

```py
import os
import torch
import torchvision as tv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from torchinfo import summary as torchinfo_summary

#cuda configs
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

#loading dataset
data_dir='/content/drive/MyDrive/tech_related/machine_learning_related/pytorch-etic/data/cat_deer_dog_horse'
#data_dir = os.path.join('..','data','cat_deer_dog_horse')
print(os.listdir(data_dir))
data_classes = os.listdir(os.path.join(data_dir,'train'))
print(data_classes)

#making torch defined dataloaders with dataset
stats = ((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), (0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010))  #means and stds of each channel in images of cifar10
train_tfms = tv.transforms.Compose([
    tv.transforms.RandomCrop(32,padding=4,padding_mode='reflect'),
    tv.transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    tv.transforms.ToTensor()
])
valid_tfms = tv.transforms.Compose([
    tv.transforms.ToTensor()
])

train_ds = tv.datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir,'train'),train_tfms)
valid_ds = tv.datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir,'test'),valid_tfms)
batch_size = 64
train_dl = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_ds,batch_size,shuffle=True,pin_memory=True)
valid_dl = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(valid_ds,batch_size,shuffle=True,pin_memory=True)

model_ = tv.models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained=False, num_classes=len(data_classes)).to(device)

#here comes the training part, finding optimum learning rate.
from fastai.vision.all import *
data = DataLoaders(train_dl,valid_dl)
learner = Learner(data, model_, loss_func=torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy, opt_func=Adam, metrics=accuracy)

lr_min,lr_steep,lr_slide,lr_valley = learner.lr_find(suggest_funcs=(minimum,steep,slide,valley))
```

I checked the runtime I used in colab and it is GPU. Can someone say what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're using the GPU. You can confirm that you are by running `next(learner.model.parameters).is_cuda` immediately prior to `lr_find`.

What jumps out is that you are not loading pretrained weights (`pretrained = False`) in your model. This would naturally slow down the total time of training. Set `pretrained` to `True` and see if you get good results quicker.

Or, if you are concerned about the per-epoch time of training, the other issue might be if your datasets are very large. Large datasets are usually  a good problem to have and, even if the per-epoch time of training is high, the total wall time for training without overfitting is probably similar or better with large datasets.

Just to be thorough, `lr_find` is not used to actually train. For that, you should use `fit` or `fit_one_cycle` with the `lr_steep` value generated by `lr_find`.